# In iText7, is there a way like iText5's calculateHeights method?

Tags: itext7

In iText5, we can get the PdfPTable's height when we need "public float calculateHeights(boolean firsttime)".

But in iText7, how can we get current table height value (especially before adding  the table to its parent element)?

I already tested "table.getHeight()" method, but it returns null.
And I also found that in a table render object I can get this value, but the limitation is that the render need to be triggered when the table is adding into its parent element, so the time is not my need.

Cause sometimes we need this value for calculation to decide the "y-axis" value.

Comment: You are aware that the height can't be calculated if the width is unknown, are you? A narrow table will require more height than a wide table. Can you show us the code that proves that you set the width?

Comment: Hi, Brian, very happy to see your reply.

Comment: I know your meaning, but in iText5, we don't need to worry about this, just call a method.
Following is a simple example, althrough set the width of a table, and a add just one string, but still can't get height value.

Table table = new Table(1);
table.setWidth(300);
table.addCell("1");

// Result: height = null
System.out.println("height = " + table.getHeight());

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In iText5, elements and information about their position/size were a bit mixed together, which allowed you to call `calculateWidths` on a `PdfPTable` element.

In iText7, this functionality is separated, which allows different kind of flexibility for rendering/layouting elements.

Thus, model elements, which a `Table` instance is an example of, do not know anything about their position or size. And calling `table.getHeight` results in `null` because `table` did not have `HEIGHT` property previously set to it.

To calculate table height, one would have to make use of the rendering functionality.

For a model element, you can get the subtree of renderers representing this model element and all its children, and `layout` it in any given area. To really know the height of a table, you would want to create an area which knowingly will be sufficient to place the whole contents of the element.

```
PdfDocument pdfDoc = ...
Document doc = ...

Table table = new Table(2)
            .addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("cell 1, 1")))
            .addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("cell 1, 2")));
LayoutResult result = table.createRendererSubTree().setParent(doc.getRenderer()).layout(
            new LayoutContext(new LayoutArea(1, new Rectangle(0, 0, 400, 1e4f))));

System.out.println(result.getOccupiedArea().getBBox().getHeight());
```

The code above prints `22.982422O` for me, but the results may vary depending on the configuration and properties of elements.

I would like to point out two important parts of the code:

1. We pass `1e4f` as the height of the `LayoutArea`, considering that this will be sufficient to place the whole table. Note that if the table cannot be placed into that height, the result will never exceed this given height and thus it will not be correct for your usecase (know the total height of the table). So make sure to pass the height which will be sufficient for placement of the whole table.
2. `.setParent(doc.getRenderer())` part is important here and is used for retrieving inheritant properties. Note that we did not set a lot of properties to `table` element, even font, but this information is essential to know the area this element would occupy. So this information will be inherited from the parent chain during `layout`. You can test this by changing the document's font: `document.setFont(newFont);`, or font size: `document.setFontSize(24);` and watching the resultant height change

Answer (score 2):

Well, due to the way the renderer framework is written in iText7, there isn't a way (yet) to calculate the height of a layout object before it is added to a parent document, since the actual calculation of the height for the layout objects happens when they are added to the a `Document` object.

You can however relayout a `Document`, allowing you to change the content of previously added elements. Using this, you can simulate the rendering of tables and get a hold of their heights when you add new elements. The `table.getHeight()` still won't work, since it retrieves the height property, and that property is currently not set anywhere in the table rendering process.

In the example below, I've written a convenience method that iterates over the renderer-tree and prints out the area each table occupies in the document, to show you how you can get the calculated heights.

The example itself adds some tables to the document, displays the occupied areas, adds some cells to each table, displays the occupied areas (they're the same since adding to an element that has been added before doesn't trigger a layout), and finally, manually triggers a relayout and displays the final occupied areas.

```
public class DelayedLayout {
    public static String DEST = "target/output/StackOverflow/DelayedLayout/delayed.pdf";

    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException, FileNotFoundException{
        File file = new File(DEST);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        new DelayedLayout().createPdf(DEST);
    }

    public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException{
        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(dest);
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);
        boolean immediateFlush = false;
        boolean relayout = true;
        //Set immediate layout to false, so the document doesn't immediatly write render-results to its outputstream
        Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc, PageSize.A4,immediateFlush);
        Table tOne = createSimpleTable();
        for(int i= 0; i< 5; i++) {
            //Add a table and some whitespace
            doc.add(tOne);

            doc.add(new Paragraph(""));

        }
        System.out.println("\nInitial layout results");
        printOccupiedAreasOfTableRenderers(doc.getRenderer());
        System.out.println("\nAdding extra cells to the table");
        addToTable(tOne);
        printOccupiedAreasOfTableRenderers(doc.getRenderer());
        System.out.println("\nForcing the document to redo the layout");
        if(relayout)doc.relayout();
        printOccupiedAreasOfTableRenderers(doc.getRenderer());
        doc.close();
    }

    /**
     * Create a very simple table
     * @return simple table
     */
    private Table createSimpleTable(){
        int nrOfCols = 3;
        int nrOfRows = 5;

        Table res = new Table(nrOfCols);
        for(int i= 0; i<nrOfRows;i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<nrOfCols;j++){
                Cell c = new Cell();
                c.add(new Paragraph("["+i+", "+j+"]"));
                res.addCell(c);
            }
        }

        return res;
    }

    /**
     * Add some extra cells to an exisiting table
     * @param tab table to add cells to
     */
    private void addToTable(Table tab){
        int nrOfRows = 5;
        int nrOfCols = tab.getNumberOfColumns();
        for(int i=0; i<nrOfRows*nrOfCols;i++){
            Cell c = new Cell();
            c.add(new Paragraph("Extra cell"+ i));
            tab.addCell(c);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Recursively iterate over the renderer tree, writing the occupied area to the console 
     * @param currentNode current renderer-node to check
     */
    private void printOccupiedAreasOfTableRenderers(IRenderer currentNode){
        if(currentNode.getClass().equals(TableRenderer.class)){
            System.out.println("Table renderer with occupied area: " + currentNode.getOccupiedArea());
        }
        for (IRenderer child:currentNode.getChildRenderers()) {
            printOccupiedAreasOfTableRenderers(child);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Alexey Subach inspired me to write a helper method to calculate the height of any IElement (works in iText 7.2.5 and java11, where the given element is a descendant of iText.Table):

```
public static float calculateElementHeight( IElement aElement, RootRenderer aRootRenderer, Rectangle aRectangle )
{
    IRenderer rendererLeft = aElement.createRendererSubTree();
    LayoutResult resultLeft = rendererLeft
            .setParent( aRootRenderer )
            .layout( new LayoutContext( new LayoutArea( 1, aRectangle ) ) );
    return resultLeft.getOccupiedArea().getBBox().getHeight();
}
```

The method expects also the rectangle as parameter in which the layout should be performed. Reason: the available width might influence the resulting height, e.g. if the content of a table cell would be wrapped because the total width is too narrow.